# Mapping RightAlt+Ctrl+a to send Ctrl+Delete?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, keymapping

I have the following map:

```
>!+a::SendInput,+{Delete}
```

It's supposed to send `Ctrl+Delete` (delete word after cursor) when I press `RightAlt+Ctrl+a` but instead it's sending a `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` signal so it's bringing up the Windows 7 menu of shutdown, start task manager etc.

How can I send the right signal?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that [Ctrl + Alt + Delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete) is hard coded and is uninterruptible. There's simply no way around it, if you press that sequence, even with the Command BlockInput enabled, Windows will re-enable input and execute the command...

Try:

```
>!^a:: ; + symbol is Shift ^ represents Ctrl key
KeyWait, RAlt ; Waits for Right Alt to be released before Ctrl Delete is sent
SendInput,{Ctrl Down}{Delete}{Ctrl Up}
Return
```

An alternative although it works the exact same way:

```
>!^a:: 
While (GetKeyState("RAlt", "P"))
    Continue
SendInput,{Ctrl Down}{Delete}{Ctrl Up}
Return
```

I'll continue to pursue other options.. at the moment I can I think of no better way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'd rather not wait for releasing RAlt because there are a lot more key combos mapped into it so it's less convenient. Any other ways? And what's with the Ctrl Up and Down part?

Comment: Trying to disable Ctrl-Alt-Delete all together, can't seem to find a straight-forward solution without messing with the scan codes and disabling alt key.

Comment: Right now this seems the best solution. Instead of waiting for the alt key I waited for LCtrl. Let me know If you come up with a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, I'll see what other solutions I can come up with.